# Expo - unwanted white bar at top with back button

Tags: react-native, react-navigation, expo

I'm trying to build an app with expo and react-native.

I have a white bar at the top with a back button. I don't understand why it is there, is this a feature of expo, react-native or react-navigation that I need to disable ?

I tried searching for any "*Bar*" component but there's really nothing, my App.js only render my own bar with a component view underneath it.

Screenshot:
https://ibb.co/QQ5fMDP

AppNavigator.js:

```
export default createAppContainer(
  createStackNavigator({
    [ROUTES.Login]: LoginScreen,
    [ROUTES.Some]: SomeScreen,
  }),
  {
    initialRouteName: ROUTES.Login,
    defaultNavigationOptions: {
      headerMode: 'none',
      headerVisible: false,
      header: null,
    },
    navigationOptions: {
      headerMode: 'none',
      headerVisible: false,
      header: null,
    },
  },
);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is likely a header that react-navigation adds automatically to the stack navigator.
If you don't want to use it, you can remove it globally

```
createStackNavigator({
  ...,
},{
  defaultNavigationOptions: {
    headerMode: 'none'
  }
});
```

or screen by screen:

```
MyComponent.navigationOptions = {
  headerMode: 'none'
};
```

See more in the [react-navigation API docs](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/stack-navigator.html).

### Edit

Looks like there's a typo in the way you set up your navigation. You'll need to change it to this:

```
export default createAppContainer(
  createStackNavigator({
    [ROUTES.Login]: LoginScreen,
    [ROUTES.Some]: SomeScreen,
  },
  {
    initialRouteName: ROUTES.Login,
    defaultNavigationOptions: {
      headerMode: 'none',
      headerVisible: false,
      header: null,
    },
    navigationOptions: {
      headerMode: 'none',
      headerVisible: false,
      header: null,
    },
  })
);
```

Note that `createStackNavigator` now has two parameters, as needed.

Comment: Thank you for the help. I tried `defaultNavigationOptions` (without typo) but it won't work. `defaultNavigationOptions: { headerMode: 'none', headerVisible: false, header: null }`

Comment: @Apolo Can you add your configuration to the question?

Comment: I was able to fix it by using createSwitchNavigator instead of createStackNavigator. However I wish I could use stack navigation with custom header

Comment: That's because the switch navigator doesn't have a header. This isn't its intended use, though, as you've said.

Comment: Looks like you have a small mistake - the second parameter object (curly braces) is in the `createAppContainer` function instead of the `createStackNavigator` function.